# Artefacts in the blender

Tags: materials

Perhaps someone knows the cause of such artefacts when working with a voxel character model.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Tvozoc, welcome .... it's not very clear what you mean by artefacts in this context. Can you please illustrate which  features you mean, so there's no doubt?  If it's the rainbow of colours, I think we'll need to be clued in about how the surface is mapped.. how colours are supposed to be allocated to faces, beforewe can make any suggestions. At the moment, this post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear', or 'needs more detail' . Please edit so we can do our best for you.

Answer (score -2):

The problem lies in the UV stretching.
UVs are concentrated in points on the palitre, but some segments are stretched across the palitre.
The .obj file doesn't have this problem and can be used for recovery.

[image: artifacts]

[image: Stretched UVs]

Comment: Please add a comment to his question instead. Answers should answer the issue of the question, not ask for precisions.

Comment: Here is the link to the project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rvQhC2ZBGH6PKqSVa0LCHnc_FNJIbQ9C/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You didn't pack the textures in the file, I still can't diagnose the problem. File > External Data > Pack Resources, then save the file and leave the link here.

Comment: These are links to a texture with a resolution .obj and on the color palette:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p5-YBRra_5nCaFtOqVEXS7Y-AMevCKXE/view?usp=drive_link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S59nzIGuRNrmray5GXuqh6Ev7ILjaZas/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Just in case, here is another link in which I copied the model as you said: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WeNhnNOV5riyFR5MJ6av4Y-FsPPsw0i/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @Tvozoc couldn't reproduce artifacts with the .obj file and a palette, found a problem in UV stretching in another file, explained it as the answer. 
You can load the .obj file or remap the UVs with correct colors.